# Apply an operator on Spark RDD repeatedly

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

Say we had a dataset stored in RDD0 already. I had a map and a reduce functions to apply on RDD0 repeatedly. Like this:

```
RDD0.cache
do{
   Val RDD1 =  RDD0.flatmap().reducebykey()
   RDD0=RDD1
   update "terminate condition"
}while("terminate condition" is false )
```

It seems that this code will create lots of shuffle file on disk. It might be caused by creating a lot of temp variable as RDD1. But, I am not sure.

Any suggestions to improve them ? The code is in scala.

Comment: why are you writing do while statements?

Comment: because I want to run apply/reduce on RDD multiple times. The "terminate condition" decides how many times to run.

Comment: aren't you running apply/reduce the same for all the loops before it is terminated?

Comment: yes. But, by map and reduce, it changes the data inside RDD0 and stores the new data in RDD1.  Checking the RDD1's data will tell whether to finish or not.

Comment: rdds are immutables. You cannot change them. You can just transform to another rdd.

Comment: yeah, you are right. That's why I need to create another RDD1. This might create a lot of problem.

Comment: do you have any actions on RDD in `update "terminate condition"`?

Comment: Actually, the "terminate condition" is decided by "comparing"  RDD0 vs RDD1. If nothing different, the coverage/terminate will happen.